# How to move Tortoise SVN Repositories when the Windows server that hosts it is no longer available

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

My development project uses VisualSVN Server v 1.1 to manage my Tortoise SVN repositories.  The windows server that hosts them became unavailable and I was forced to use the ISP's recovery app to pull the source data down to another server.  I took the following steps.

1. Copied the folders repositories and svnrepos from old server to new.
2. I installed Visual SVN on the new server.  When installing I told the app about the repositories folder hoping it would magically figure out what's going on (funny thing about magic, as we all know it does not exist).
3. I updated the dns for the sub domain to point to the ip of the new server.
4. Now when I open visual svn, i do in fact see the foldes, users, and groups (a little bit of magic here).  But unfortunately all repositories when opened display the error "Expected FS format '2'; found format '3'"

So the question is, how do I fix the mess without disrupting the files and folders?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the [format of the repository](https://serverfault.com/questions/354855/subversion-how-to-tell-the-format-of-an-existing-repository) is different to what this version of the server expects.  Subversion basically has two different internal representations for the repository - BDB (which is now deprecated) and FSFS (which has been the default for now repositories for a while now). I suspect that the version on the old server used BDB and the server you're now using can't cope with that.

I would suggest the best course of action is firstly to try to replicate as closely as possible the old server. You mention VisualSVN server v1.1 - is this what you had originally or what you're now using?  Try to install the same version of VisualSVN that you had running on the old server.  If that can't read the repository format then maybe there's an extra addon you need to install.  If the original server was a different OS then set up a machine with that OS (if it was a linux server then try creating a Virtual Machine with a linux install disk).

Once you have got an instance of the server that can recognise the format of the data, do an [svnadmin dump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html) which will create a backup of the SVN data in a portable format. You can then either update the server to the latest version of SVN or transfer to the machine that will be the actual server (eg if you had to use a VM to get the data out).  You can then import the backup using [svnadmin load](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html).

Note that if you had any hooks set up (eg precommit hooks) then these aren't saved in an `svnadmin dump`, so you'll need to copy these manually. Same goes for the configuration files and permission data.